# how lazy is haskell when dealing with complicated program flow

Tags: haskell

I was wondering how smart/lazy  Haskell is. Can I always be sure that Haskell will only do what is necessary to generate a certain output?

Comment: Note that Haskell is non-strict, which is *not* the same thing as lazy. See https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_vs._non-strict

Comment: I find it a bit odd that you write "The Haskell interpreter" instead of just Haskell or GHC. Do you mean GHCi? And why not just consider compiled programs?

Comment: There is nothing special about lists, these are data structures that can be defined in Haskell and thus the laziness of a simple structure like a list is the same as that of other data structures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**

Haskell specifies a denotational semantics for its core lambda-like calculus, and you can rely on that semantics. Additionally, there is a metatheory proof that a particular reduction order -- known colloquially as "lazy evaluation" -- realizes that semantics; and so many people use that as their mental model of how Haskell programs behave.

There are two broad categories of ways that a Haskell program may end up evaluating more than necessary:

- The Haskell implementation may choose to evaluate more. GHC uses lazy evaluation in most places, but I believe it will use other evaluation orders for efficiency in some cases. You could also look at the [Eager Haskell](http://csg.csail.mit.edu/pubs/haskell.html) project, which is attempting to use another implementation strategy. In principle, an implementation would be within its rights to choose to speculatively fork some computations to another thread (and then throw away the results if they weren't needed). And so on and so forth -- there are many possible variations on this theme.
- The denotational semantics specified may demand more evaluation than "necessary". For example, one that occasionally trips up beginners:

  ```
    primes :: [Int]
    primes = 2 : filter prime [3,5..]

    prime :: Int -> Bool
    prime x = and [x `mod` p /= 0 | p <- primes, p < x]
  ```

  When checking whether `3` should be in the list `primes`, it is in fact not necessary to check any of the elements of `primes` past `2`, because the sequence is strictly monotonically increasing. But Haskell is not (does not try to be) smart enough to notice that; it will go straight on trying to check the rest of the `primes` and end up in an infinite loop instead of giving the list of primes.

  An even smaller example: you could think that `x && False` is always `False`, but `x` will typically be evaluated anyway, because the semantics says this should be an infinite loop if `x` is. (Contrast `False && x`, which typically does not result in evaluating `x`.)

That said, when you say "complex structure", one thing that comes to mind is: does Haskell do the laziness thing *even with custom data types that I define*? That is, do complex structures like hash maps and balanced trees and k-d trees and so forth get treated lazily? The answer there is *yes*, at least for GHC; there is nothing fundamentally special about any of the types in the `Prelude` except `IO`. Lists, booleans, `Maybe`s, and so forth are lazy not because the compiler knows special things about them, but simply as a consequence of the lazy evaluation reduction rules specified by Haskell and their declarations as types.

Of course, there are ways to opt-out of laziness. Some of the structures you will see on Hackage do that in various ways; but don't worry, usually this will be declared in their documentation.

Comment: As far as I know, the Haskell 2010 report doesn't specify a reduction order for the lambda calculus-like language it translates into.

Comment: @Noughtmare Absolutely right, thank you for that precision. Clarification incoming.